# conda environment for Pyspark - Redhat cluster but Mac computer

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, virtualenv, conda, redhat

I need to make a Python environment to be packaged with conda-pack to be used in the archives configuration option in Pyspark (https://conda.github.io/conda-pack/spark.html). The cluster that I want to run Pyspark on does not have Internet access, so I need to prepare the conda environment on my local computer (Mac operating system) and scp it into the cluster, which runs on Redhat.

How can I prepare the conda environment when the operating systems are different?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Made the Python environment on a virtual machine (VirtualBox) using the free installation of RedHat distributed for developers. Packaging the environment using conda on RHEL 8.2 is compatible with RHEL 7.7